# Restart container within pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a pod `test-1495806908-xn5jn` with 2 containers. I'd like to restart one of them called `container-test`. Is it possible to restart a single container within a pod and how? If not, how do I restart the pod?

The pod was created using a `deployment.yaml` with:

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 210, accepted):

> Is it possible to restart a single container

Not through `kubectl`, although depending on the setup of your cluster you can "cheat" and `docker kill the-sha-goes-here`, which will cause kubelet to restart the "failed" container (assuming, of course, the restart policy for the Pod says that is what it should do)

> how do I restart the pod

That depends on how the Pod was created, but based on the Pod name you provided, it appears to be under the oversight of a ReplicaSet, so you can just `kubectl delete pod test-1495806908-xn5jn` and kubernetes will create a new one in its place (the new Pod will have a different name, so do not expect `kubectl get pods` to return `test-1495806908-xn5jn` ever again)

Comment: The default restart policy is always restart

Comment: If I can do this: `docker kill the-sha-goes-here` , then why not do `docker container restart the-sha-goes-here` instead? why rely on `kubelet` to restart it? Anyway, the real problem is that where do I run the `docker` command even be it to kill the container. On `could-shell`, `docker` does not show the containers from the k8s clusters!

Comment: A good suggestion is to have the `POD_NAME` as an environment variable within your running containers. That way, when you need to add some logic to restart the pod/container, you can easily reference it by using the env variable defined `$POD_NAME`

Comment: I feel like this requires an up-to-date answer (I can't provide yet).  Docker is not a supported compute engine for k8s going forward.  Perhaps there is a `crictl` command or a more complete instruction for adjusting rolebindings and using `kubectl` to delete / reapply a pod or a specific container.

Comment: The correct answer is to move the container to its own pod

Comment: instead of `docker kill`, what about just `kill`ing the container main process directly on the host, or `kill 1` inside the container (if it is not a distroless image, or use an ephemeral container)?

Answer (score 114):

There are cases when you want to restart a specific container instead of deleting the pod and letting Kubernetes recreate it.

Doing a `kubectl exec POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME /sbin/killall5` worked for me.

*(I changed the command from `reboot` to `/sbin/killall5` based on the below recommendations.)*

Comment: Not every container has `reboot`; I had more luck with executing `/sbin/killall5` instead; that kills all processes, and the container will exit.

Comment: And not every container has root user ;)

Comment: -1, because... You're using the side effect of 'reboot' killing all processes and Kubernetes recovery of it. It's making a lot of assumptions: running as root, availability of the binary in the container, a restartPolicy that's enabled, etc. Also, this clutters the logs about a failure of the process, which isn't ideal.

Comment: So looks like alpine doesn't have the killall, but /sbin/reboot works great.  `kubectl exec POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME /sbin/reboot` worked like a charm

Comment: @Atif can I prevent losing my changes inside the container after executing `reboot`? e.g., I install vim, but after calling reboot I don't find vim (the same for any file change if not persisted).

Comment: Does rebooting drop your changes? I would think you would only look the changes if the POD is killed by k8s and respawned.  If you need tools for debugging, I think there is a trick to tack on a debugging container as well. You might want to google how that works.  Haven't tried it myself

Answer (score 100):

Now, there is a `kubectl rollout restart` sub-command added in [Kubernetes 1.15](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md).

Examples:

```bash
# Restart all deployments in test-namespace namespace
kubectl rollout restart deployment -n test-namespace
  
# Restart a deployment
kubectl rollout restart deployment/nginx
  
# Restart a daemon set
kubectl rollout restart daemonset/abc
  
# Restart deployments with the app=nginx label
kubectl rollout restart deployment --selector=app=nginx
```

See also, https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_rollout/kubectl_rollout_restart/.

---

Both pod and container are ephemeral, try to use the following command to stop the specific container and the k8s cluster will restart a new container.

```bash
kubectl exec -it [POD_NAME] -c [CONTAINER_NAME] -- /bin/sh -c "kill 1"
```

This will send a `SIGTERM` signal to process 1, which is the main process running in the container. All other processes will be children of process 1, and will be terminated after process 1 exits. See the [kill manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html) for other signals you can send.

Comment: I tried other answers and this one was the only that worked for me, it seems to me that it is the most general one.

Comment: how do I get the container name that is running inside a pod??

Comment: My Alpine container went into an unhealthy status of some sort when I tried this.  kubectl get po shows Error in the status column for the pod..

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN you can use the deploy name and it will select the pod automatically

Comment: Worked after trying other suggested commands. Thanks.

Comment: I am frustrated why other people says there is no way to do that, while there is.
It worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Does this solution also remove the container/pod? Because all not-persisted changes inside the containers are simply gone.

Comment: This causes my "not persisted" changes to disappear. Can I somehow keep my changes in the container and not lose them after restarting it?

Comment: This is the best one for me. The only issue I had with this is that I was needed to change the container run to run from the process [entry point](https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/) so the process will get the signal.

Answer (score 29):

#### I m using

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment [deployment_name]
```

or

```
kubectl delete pod [pod_name]
```

Comment: kubectl rollout restart deployment  -n [NAMESPACE]   [deployment_name]

Comment: kubectl delete pods POD_NAME

Answer (score 25):

The whole reason for having kubernetes is so it manages the containers for you so you don't have to care so much about the lifecyle of the containers in the pod.

Since you have a `deployment` setup that uses `replica set`. You can delete the pod using `kubectl delete pod test-1495806908-xn5jn` and kubernetes will manage the creation of a new pod with the 2 containers without any downtime. Trying to manually restart single containers in pods negates the whole benefits of kubernetes.

Comment: I experienced downtime as my terminating pod's process became 0/1

Comment: You need to be careful stating "without any downtime". It depends on your exact configuration. Plus zero-downtime has challenges on its own.

Comment: When I delete a pod in my deployment with only 1 replica, I always experience downtime.

Comment: it is safe if it is your dev environment :D

Answer (score 16):

All the above answers have mentioned deleting the pod...but if you have many pods of the same service then it would be tedious to delete each one of them...

Therefore, I propose the following solution, **restart**:

- 1) Set scale to zero :

  ```
   kubectl scale deployment <<name>> --replicas=0 -n service
  ```

  *The above command will terminate all your pods with the name `<<name>>`*
- 2) To start the pod again, set the replicas to more than 0

  ```
  kubectl scale deployment <<name>> --replicas=2 -n service
  ```

  *The above command will start your pods again with 2 replicas.*

Comment: Question was asking about how to restart a single container within a pod.

Comment: Also, scaling down to 0 pods will not work for highly available applications. Use `kubectl patch deployment <deployment name> -p "{\"spec\": {\"template\": {\"metadata\": { \"labels\": {  \"redeploy\": \"$(date +%s)\"}}}}}"` instead. This will update the deployment and therefore initiate recreation of all pods managed by it according to rolling update strategy.

Answer (score 5):

We use a pretty convenient command line to force re-deployment of fresh images on integration pod.
We noticed that our alpine containers all run their "sustaining" command on PID 5. Therefore, sending it a `SIGTERM` signal takes the container down. `imagePullPolicy` being set to `Always` has the kubelet re-pull the latest image when it brings the container back.

```
kubectl exec -i [pod name] -c [container-name] -- kill -15 5
```

Comment: what does -15 and 5 represent?

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias it's tucked into the description above, but in `kill -15 5` you're running the kill command to send signal "-15" to the process with the PID 5.  This is how you tell a process that you would like for it to terminate (SIGTERM) and have it take the time to clean up any opened resources (temp files, rollback db transactions, close connections, whatever).  Contrasted with -9 (SIGKILL), kills the process immediately, not allowing it to clean up any opened resources.

Answer (score 4):

```
kubectl exec -it POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME bash - then kill 1
```

Assuming the container is run as root which is not recommended.

In my case when I changed the application config, I had to reboot the container which was used in a sidecar pattern, I would kill the PID for the spring boot application which is owned by the docker user.

Comment: If you write `kubectl exec -it ${POD_NAME?} -c ${CONTAINER_NAME?} bash ...`, it makes it much easier for people to copy/paste.

Comment: Docker does not allow you to kill -9 PID 1

Answer (score 4):

Restarting a single container is very much possible, but the ways might differ depending on the cluster configuration. In general you need these two conditions:

- Have the pod set to `restartPolicy: Always` (default for most workloads, so that's easy)
- Make the main container process stop without deleting the pod. That's the interesting part.

Remember that a container is just a little fence ([namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces)) around a process (and network, filesystem, etc.) on someone's (usually pretty generic) Linux server (that's called a `node` in the Kubernetes jargon). This means:

- **If you are `root`** at the node where the container runs, you can wreak havoc I surely don't need to describe, right? But most of the time you are not. And that's a good thing.
- **If the container has a shell**, and you can `kubectl exec` to it

  ```bash
  kubectl exec -it $POD -c $CONTAINER -- sh -c 'kill 1'
  ```

  This will send a `TERM` signal to the process `1`, after which most well-behaved processes die more or less gracefully. Process `1` is usually the container's main process (or [sometimes not](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/#understanding-process-namespace-sharing)), after whose death the container gets torn down and `kubelet` takes over restarting it again. If the process is stubborn, you might try `kill -9 1`, which should kill it for good, but again YMMV.
- **If the container is "distroless"** (i.e. has no shell), you can't use the trick above, but [there's a way](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container) if your cluster version is at least 1.25 (but maybe even older):

  ```bash
  kubectl debug -it --image=busybox $POD --target=$CONTAINER -- sh -c 'kill 1'
  ```

  This will create a new "ephemeral container" in the pod that will land pretty much in the same fence as the `--target` one's. This allows you to see the target process and kill it, doing so with tools available in the supplied `--image`. I used `busybox` as that's tiny and gets the job done, but you sure can use any fatter image like `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 3):

There was an issue in `coredns` pod, I deleted such pod by

```
kubectl delete pod -n=kube-system coredns-fb8b8dccf-8ggcf
```

Its pod will restart automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is old and already answered, but I thought I'd chip in with my method.

Whenever I want to do this, I just make a minor change to the pod's container's image field, which causes kubernetes to restart just the container.

If you can't switch between 2 different, but equivalent tags (like `:latest` / `:1.2.3` where latest is **actually** version 1.2.3) then you can always just switch it quickly to an invalid tag (I put an X at the end like `:latestX` or something) and then re-edit it and remove the X straight away afterwards, this does cause the container to fail starting with an image pull error for a few seconds though.

So for example:

```sh
kubectl edit po my-pod-name
```

Find the `spec.containers[].name` you want to kill, then find it's `image`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  #...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: main-container
    #...
  - name: container-to-restart
    image: container/image:tag
#...
```

You would search for your container-to-restart and then update it's image to something different which will force kubernetes to do a controlled restart for you.

Answer (score 1):

Killing the process specified in the Dockerfile's `CMD` / `ENTRYPOINT` works for me. (The container restarts automatically)

Rebooting was not allowed in my container, so I had to use this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The correct, but likely less popular answer, is that if you need to restart one container in a pod then it shouldn't be in the same pod. You can't restart single containers in a pod by design. Just move the container out into it's own pod. From the docs

> Pods that run a single container. The "one-container-per-Pod" model is
> the most common Kubernetes use case; in this case, you can think of a
> Pod as a wrapper around a single container; Kubernetes manages Pods
> rather than managing the containers directly.
>
> Note: Grouping multiple co-located and co-managed containers in a
> single Pod is a relatively advanced use case. You should use this
> pattern only in specific instances in which your containers are
> tightly coupled.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with ways to restart a container. What I found for me was this solution:

**Dockerfile:**

```
...
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/bootstrap.sh" ]
```

**/app/bootstrap.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
/app/startWhatEverYouActuallyWantToStart.sh &
tail -f /dev/null
```

Whenever I want to restart the container, I kill the process with `tail -f /dev/null` which I find with

```
kill -TERM `ps --ppid 1 | grep tail | grep -v -e grep | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Following that command, all the processes except for the one with `PID==1` will be killed and the entrypoint, in my case `bootstrap.sh` will be executed (again).

That's for the part "restart" - which is not really a restart but it does what you wish, in the end. For the part with limiting restarting the container named `container-test` you could pass on the container name to the container in question (as the container name would otherwise not be available inside the container) and then you can decide whether to do the above `kill`.
That would be something like this in your `deployment.yaml`:

```
    env:
    - name: YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME
      value: container-test
```

**/app/startWhatEverYouActuallyWantToStart.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
...
CONDITION_TO_RESTART=0
...
if [ "$YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME" == "container-test" -a $CONDITION_TO_RESTART -eq 1 ]; then
    kill -TERM `ps --ppid 1 | grep tail | grep -v -e grep | awk '{print $1}'`
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes no one knows which OS the pod has, pod might not have `sudo` or `reboot` altogether.

Safer option is to take a snapshot and recreate pod.

```
kubectl get <pod-name> -o yaml > pod-to-be-restarted.yaml; 
kubectl delete po <pod-name>; 
kubectl create -f pod-to-be-restarted.yaml
```

Answer (score -1):

```
kubectl delete pods POD_NAME
```

This command will delete the pod and restart another automatically.