# Restart server running inside Kubernetes Node

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I am having a IBM cloud powered kubernetes cluster. That cluster currently have only 1 node.
I verified running the command `kubectl get nodes`.
There are few servers which are running in that node. I want to restart one of those server.
How can I get into the node and perform a restart for the required server?
I tried ssh, but [this link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_troubleshoot_clusters.html#cs_ssh_worker) says it cannot be done directly.

Comment: Few servers running or few services running ? You can login to any worker node using creds or SSH. Since you are using IBM provided services you can use the IP to login

Comment: by servers, I meant services which run as servers like web server (nginx), elasticsearch servers.Regarding ssh using IP, I tried `ssh <user>@<IP>` but it timed out.

Comment: When you say "server" do you actually mean "Kubernetes pod"?

Comment: The question needs to be formatted and explained well. Inside a node there are pods running - these pods are nothing but applications that are running as docker container using k8 as orchestration tool. The SSH will work only if the keys are available with you. Go through the doc if IBM again to check the keys or password configuration of the k8 cluster

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes. They are different kubernetes pod. In total, I got 10 different pods, and want to restart one of them. Additionallly, is there is a way to access the directory where the configs are stored inside the pod, it will be great.

Comment: @yashbagarka Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123457/kubernetes-restart-container-within-pod

Comment: @yashbagarka Any idea how I can confirm if I delete a pod, kubernetes will default create a new pod with the same config.

Comment: You should manage your Pods with Deployments, and when you do this, when you `kubectl delete pod ...` it will get recreated.  You should almost never need to ssh to a Node, get interactive shells in Pods, or directly change files in Pods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your main questions are:
"how to restart a pod", "how to ssh to a entity in which my service is running" and "how to see if I deleted a Pod".

First of all, most of this questions are already answered on StackOverflow. Second of all you need to get familiar with Kubernetes basic terminology and how things work in here. You can do that in any Kubernetes introduction or in [documentation.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/#kubernetes-objects)

Answering the questions:

1) About restarting you can find information [here](https://medium.com/devopslinks/how-to-restart-kubernetes-pod-7c702ca984c1). Or if you have running deployment, deleting a pod will result in pod recreation.

2) you can use `kubectl exec`as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/#getting-a-shell-to-a-container):
`kubectl exec -ti pod_name sh(or bash)`

3) to see your pods, run `kubectl get pods` after you run `kubectl delete pod name -n namespace` you can run `kubectl get pods -w` to see changing status of deleted pod and new one being spawned. Or you will notice that there is a new pod running but with different `NAME`.

Comment: Thanks for answering the questions. The comments helped me understand what I was really looking for and was planning to modify the question and add the answer myself this weekend. Thanks again.